# Run function on view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire2 to show data real-time on my html page, it connects via `async`.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of Reminders | async">
   <!-- display below -->
   <ion-label>{{item.name}}</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

On the typescript side:

```
import {FirebaseListObservable, AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
Reminders: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
//Call database
this.Reminders = db.list('/xxx/');
```

Everything works great, my question now is on the view side of things, `{{item.name}}` is actually encrypted so I want to call a function or find a way to decrypt before showing, as it's using `async` I don't know if it's possible as logging `this.Reminders` only gives me an Observable, is there a way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define a function in your controller to decrypt your data:

```js
decrypt(value) {
  // ...
  // decrypt logic
  // ...
  return decryptedValue;
}
```

Then you can use it in your template:

```html
{{decrypt(item.name)}}
```

When you're `Reminders` get loaded and your [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) kicks in, `item.name` will get passed into your decrypt function and display the decrypted text.